# How to speed up the loading of images from a subdomain?

Tags: html, performance, cpanel

I have a very strange problem with a website: for some unknown reason it loads very slow some images.

For example: There are 16 images to load ( each image is .jpg, around 10k ) and every time 3-4 of this images are (random) loaded in 4-5 seconds and all others in a good time 600ms.

Is insane that to load 30-40k of 3-4 images the Waterfall is >= 15s by considering also that the domain is SSL, have CloudFlare active and is running on a good dedicated server with cPanel.

Are several days that I'm trying to find a solution and I have already: try to disable cloudflare, try to load the images from a subdomain, try to compress the images, try several .htaccess settings.

Regarding lazyload, in this case it can't help me because all 16 images are in the browser view ( like the youtube homepage  )

GTMetrix report ID: cA72pYL1

Any suggestion is good, thank you a lot.

--- Additional informations and tests ---

- Using cPanel - Apache
- To load an image of 10k now the average is around 0.7s
- Any error log ( web/server side )
- The rest of website/server load without problems

Comment: have you considered converting them to base 64 images ?

Comment: @Taki How does this help? Also: Browsers can cache images, but not base64 strings.

Comment: yes no cache, but The main benefit is that a webpage does not have to load an external image. Reducing the things a webpage has to load will naturally make that page faster, i don't think the OP is asking about caching the images but loading them fast from the first time you access the webpage.

Comment: @Taki Thank you for your suggestion, but in this case I'm unable to use base64 images.

Comment: oh,ok, sorry my suggestion can't match your case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using base 64 images ?

Go to : https://www.base64-image.de/

Upload your image and it will give you the `base64`

replace the `src` of your images like :

```
<img src="example.png">
```

with

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAADSCAMAAABThmYtAAAAXVB">
```

here's an explination of what that is : [Base64 encoding images](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/base64-images.html)

[When to Base64 Encode Images (and When Not To)](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/)

Comment: Thank you Taki for your answer - unfortunately I can't use base64 images on this website because there are over 500k posts ( so over 500k images ) and also because each page have around 80 images.

Comment: oh,ok, sorry my suggestion can't match your case.

Answer (score 0):

How does the rest of your site perform? You've tried several things from the image perspective, what about looking at the site perspective?

- Check your logs (web and system) - any errors?
- Are other aspects of your site performing as expected? Page loads, form submission...If not then the images may not be the root issue.
- Did you make any changes recently?  Have these images always loaded this way, or was there a time when they loaded consistently?
- Is it always the same images that load more slowly? If so, then investigate what is different with those files.
- Or, is it always the same time span (from start of loading images to moment of slow down) when the loading slows down? If so, investigate your caching, buffering, network & bandwidth settings.

I don't know if this is possible, but can you try loading these images on a different web server?  (Trying to eliminate possibilities here.)

Comment: Thank you for your interesting, very appreciated. The rest of the website loads very good, any problem detected. 1 ) Any error log ( wordpress and cPanel ). 2) All website performs very good. 3) I have just configured the server 1 week ago, any particular change. 4) Images load slow randomly. 5) Allways different, please check this report ( gtmetrix.com/reports/porneey.com/K0y1OW50 ) - Unfortunatelly I'm unable to test another server at the moment - Thank you very much for all.